# How to convert an int to hex (uint8) and split it into 2 bytes

Tags: c++, hex, byte, sysex

In c++ i'm trying to convert to an int to uint8 (or char) hex value. Then spitting them into 2 bytes. (I'm sending sysex data to a synth)

For example an int of 1 should return 2 variables: 0x0 and 0x1
an int of 120 (hex 78) should return 0x7 and 0x8

I've been trying with stringstream and atoi but can't seem to get it to work..

Ok Sorry, clarififation (had to drive 1000km yesterday and posted in a hurry) The code I'm working on is to send sysex over midi to a synth.

I have following problem: I receive 2 doubles (from 2 sliders)

double a,b;

Double a needs to be converted to hex (uint8), double b needs to be converted to hex, and then split into 2 uint8 variables.

Then i need to put them in an array of uint8's like this:

```
 const uint8 rawSysEx[13] = {0x65, 0x16, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, converteda, convertedb1, convertedb2, 0x2, 0x4, 0x4, 0x5, 0x4};
```

Hope this clarifies.

*edit

```
                       int noteNumber = currentMessage.getNoteNumber();
                   noteNumber = trunc((noteNumber*2.125*10.0)/10.0);
                   hexNoteNumber = static_cast<char>(noteNumber);
```

- Solution: I learned that a signed char has values from -127 to + 127 and that unsigned char has values from 0 to 255 so this is the code that works: thank you all for the input

  ```
                       const auto ucx {static_cast<unsigned char>(noteNumber)};
                   char split1 = ucx & 0xf;

                   char split2 = ucx >> 4u;
  ```

Comment: If you just want to split a value into two hex digit values: `uint8 in; /* input in */ uint8 out1 = in & 0xf, out2 = in >> 4u;`

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you encounter? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Ok i tried this but to no avail: std::stringstream sstreamkitDialValue;
                   sstreamkitDialValue << std::hex << kitDialValue - 1;
                   std::string kitDialValueHex = sstreamkitDialValue.str();
                   kitNoteto8 = atoi (kitDialValueHex.substr(1, 3).c_str ());

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'hex value'. Hex is a representation, not a value type.

Comment: You should [edit] clarifications into your question, code in comments doesn't really work

Comment: @user207421 It may be out of OP bounds but, C++ precedes a hexadecimal value that it prints with the characters "0x" to make it clear that the value is in base 16. Is hexadecimal value here written accidentally?

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev -- by default the C++ standard streams do not show the base prefix. You can turn the prefix on with the manipulator `std::showbase` and off with `std::noshowbase`.

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev Of course, but it's irrelevant. That's a convention used by the compiler. The OP is trying to do something or other at runtime.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat you where right! Works perfectly, thank you so much! I've been banned apprantly to post anwsers so don't know how to close this thread. Thank you all.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat ok, so not just yet :D the conversion goes well for ints upto 127 beyond that I get weird values, any ideas?

Comment: Cannot confirm. It works for the full range of `uint8_t`: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4df814546d2a52a1). There must be something else. Please, make a [mcve]. There are things in your question which make me uncertain about your intention. (I admit I haven't any experience with sysex, and google didn't help much.) My original comment just addressed the original question - to split one 8 bit unsigned into two "hex digit values"...

Comment: What is the range of values you receive from the sliders in `double a, b`? Considering the fact that `double`s store floating point values in 8 bytes, and you intend to convert into 1 unsigned byte and 2 unsigned bytes, there is much room for speculation... (I mean, there are multiple ways of conversion imaginable but most (all?) of them come with some kind of loss.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat see edit above I actually take in the value of the slider into an int because the value doesn't have decimals. So it will always be between 0 and 255, then i need to spilt that value in 2 variables of 0 to 127 each